# Report KDP royalties on Schedule C or Schedule E?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099-misc

I have some royalty income from selling an eBook on Amazon through Kindle Direct Publishing.  I received a 1099-MISC for this income, which is listed in Box 2 "Royalties".  It is my understanding that I must report this income on either a Schedule C (profit or loss from business) or a Schedule E (supplemental income and loss).

What is the difference between these two Schedules, and in what circumstances would I report royalties on one or the other?  Is there a difference in how the income is taxes between the two Schedules?  Also, I have a small expense with regard to designing the cover of my eBook.  I believe I could write this off with a Schedule C.  Could I write off this expenses in a Schedule E?  It really is a small expense ($5) and not likely to affect my tax burden.

(I understand and acknowledge that any answers or comments given here are not to be construed as official and legal tax advice.  I assume all consequences for decisions made based on information, possibly imperfect, given here).